# SqlBulcopy metodo WriteToServer demora demasiado vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle, sql-server-2014

Al crear un objeto de la clase `sqlBulkCopy` y mandar a llamar el método `writeToServer` pasandole como parametro un `OracleDataReader` este demora mas de 15 minutos, el numero de rows que quiero copiar son cerca de 140000, ya he revisado la tabla a la que quiero hacer la copia y no tiene `triggers`,`index`,`constraints`.

```
Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
Dim odbReader As OracleDataReader = Nothing 
 odbReader = funOracle_ExecQuery_RDR(lConnOra, strQuery, False, "", strMsgErr)

try
{
bulkCopy.BatchSize = 32768 
bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 16384
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(odbReader)
}catch(Exception e)
{
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
}
```

Comment: ¿cual es la query que estas ejecutando?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: y pq decis que demora mucho? basado en que cosa?

Comment: Por favor incluye un [mcve]. Y explícanos por qué incluístes la etiqueta `sql-server-2014` si tu pregunta trata de Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

**UTILIZALO ASÍ...   KeepIdentity**

```
SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity

using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(this.GetConnectionString(), SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
{
sbc.BatchSize = 10000;
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("COL1", "TO_COL1");
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("COL2", "TO_COL2");
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("COL_N", "TO_COLN");
// Finally write to server
sbc.WriteToServer(dt);
sbc.Close();
}
```

Saludos.